# Run an observable when another one emits, return both result

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
dialog.afterClosed()
      .pipe(
        filter((result) => result),
        mergeMap((result) => this.unitService.importPack(result.file))
      )
      .subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result); // I need the result of both, not only the mergeMap result
        this.updateStateAfterUpload(result.file, 'imported');
      });
```

The issue here is that the `result` in my subscription is the result of the observable returned in my `mergeMap` operator, but I actually need to use both - the one returned from my `afterClosed()` observable AND the one returned by the `mergeMap` operator.

How I can return the result of both observables in my subscription?

Comment: Have you looked at [fork join](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Comment: @UmutEsen forkjoin emits the last values of closed observables. In this case, the second observable is using the result of the first one.

Comment: Use mergeAll https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/mergeall.html

Comment: @NarendraSinghRathore `In many cases you can use mergeMap as a single operator instead!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dialog.afterClosed().pipe(
  mergeMap(result1 => this.unitService.importPack(result.file).pipe(
    map(result2 => ({ result1, result2 }))
  ))
).subscribe(({ result1, result2 }) => { ... });
```

Map the result of the second request to return the result you want. Here, I return an object of type `{ result1: any, result2: any }`

Comment: Looks good! but there is an error when using the syntax in the `map` operator of your answer (`TS2695: Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects` ).

Comment: Indeed, I forgot parenthesis : `map(result2 => ({ result1, result2 }))`